# Уже скачанный объект для pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_patch, sep='|')
```

прекрасно качает и парсит файл формата csv в dataframe.
А как ему вскормить объект уже скачанный с помощью

```
import httpx

r = httpx.get('https://site.org/file.csv')
```

Например конкретно вот [этот](http://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/dynamic/SymDir/nasdaqlisted.txt)

Хочется скорости, по факту httpx.get .text.splitlines() в цикле разбрасывает файл в словарь раз в 10 быстрее чем pd.read_csv скачивает и парсит в dataframe...

Comment: Конечно будет быстрее, стрелять из пушки по воробьям и забивать гвозди микроскопом вообще занятия малопродуктивные. Модуль `csv` Вам в помощь. Все зависит от того, что на выходе Вы хотите получить.

Comment: Объект Dataframe хочу получить. С максимальной скоростью, вроде посыл понятный в вопросе. Обсудить микроскопы, оружие или столярное дело я бы выбрал другой форум.
Про модуль csv понятно, но здесь вроде приветствуются примеры кода.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется нашел.

```
import io
import httpx
import pandas as pd


res = httpx.get('https://site.org/file.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.text), sep='|')
```

Это в 4-5 раз быстрее чем просто pd.read_csv('https://site.org/file.csv', sep='|')
Но всё равно в 2 раза медленнее чем в словарь без Pandas...